# sparql empty result for dbpedia-owl:influenced property

Tags: properties, sparql, dbpedia, empty-list

I am trying to retrieve the value of the dbpedia-owl:influenced in this page e.g: Andy_Warhol

The query I write is:

```
PREFIX rsc : http://dbpedia.org/resource
PREFIX dbpedia-owl :http://dbpedia.org/ontology

SELECT ?o WHERE {
   rsc:Andy_Warhol dbpedia-owl:infuenced ?o .
}
```

but it is EMPTY.

Strange is that when I have the same query for another property from the ontology type like "birthPlace", the sparql engine gives the result back:

```
SELECT ?o WHERE {
  rsc:Andy_Warhol dbpedia-owl:birthplace ?o .
}
```

which is a link to another resource:
`dbpedia.org/resource/Pittsburgh`

I am just confused how to write this query?

Comment: Where and how are you running these queries?  When I run them at the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) I don't get any results for either query.

Comment: It looks like your prefixes are bad.  You don't want to query for `http://dbpedia.org/resourceAndy_Warhol`;  you want to query for `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andy_Warhol`.

Answer (score 2):

besides several formal errors addressed in the answer of @Joshua, there is also the semantic problem that the properties you are looking for - in this case - seem to be found on the entities that **were influenced**.

this query might give you the desired results

```
PREFIX rsc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?s WHERE {
    ?s dbpedia-owl:influencedBy rsc:Andy_Warhol .
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20rsc%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20?s%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?s%20dbpedia-owl%3ainfluencedBy%20rsc%3aAndy_Warhol%20.%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here.  One is that the SPARQL, as presented, isn't correct.  I edited to make the prefix syntax legal, but the prefixes were still wrong (they didn't end with a final slash).  You don't want to be querying for `http://dbpedia.org/resourceAndy_Warhol` after all; you want to query for `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andy_Warhol`.  Some [standard namespaces](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) for DBpedia are listed on their [SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  Using those namespaces and the SPARQL endpoint, we can ask for *all* the triples that have `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andy_Warhol` as the subject with this query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  dbpedia:Andy_Warhol ?p ?o .
}
```

In the results produced there, you'll see the one using `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace` (note the captial P in `birthPlace`), but you won't see any triples with the predicate `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/infuenced`, so it makes sense that your first query has no results.  Do you have some reason to suppose that there should be some results?